# Derive $E(X^k)$ I need help with the substitution piece.

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

If $X\sim\mathrm{WEI}(\theta,\beta)$, derive $E(X^k)$ assuming $k > -\beta$.

Note that $X\sim\mathrm{WEI}(\theta,\beta)=\dfrac{\beta}{\theta^\beta}x^{\beta -1}e^{-(x/\theta)^\beta}$

I know to start with the following and I know my only issue is just the calculus that goes with this.  I would appreciate a break down of the substitution and integration.

$$E(X^k)=\int_0^\infty x^k \frac{\beta}{\theta^\beta}x^{\beta -1} e^{-(x/\theta)^\beta} \, dx$$

$$=\frac{\beta}{\theta^\beta}\int_0^\infty x^{\beta+k-1}e^{-(x/\theta)^\beta} \, dx$$

$(x/\theta)^\beta=t$ Then $dt=\frac{\beta}{x}(\frac{x}{\theta})^\beta$ and $x=t^\frac{1}{\beta}\theta$

I think I am on the right track but I do not know how to substitute in x? Does this change my integral limits? I really would appreciate any help but not skipping too much on the integral.

Thanks!
I have looked at similar questions and on the internet and these did not contain the help I am looking for!

$$E(X^k)=\theta^k\Gamma(1+\frac{\kappa}{\beta})$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change of variables: $({x}/{\theta})^{\beta}=t$ with

$$dx=d(t^{1/\beta}\theta)=\frac{\theta}{\beta}t^{1/\beta-1}dt$$

yields

$$\frac{\beta}{\theta^{\beta}}\int_0^{\infty}x^{\beta+k-1}e^{-({x}/{\theta})^{\beta}}dx=\frac{\beta}{\theta^{\beta}}\int_0^{\infty}(t^{1/\beta}\theta)^{\beta+k-1}e^{-t}\frac{\theta}{\beta}t^{1/\beta-1}dt$$

$$=\theta^{k}\int_0^{\infty}t^{k/\beta}e^{-t}dt=\theta^k\Gamma\left(1+\frac{k}{\beta}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you.  After lots of scratch paper I did end up getting this last night! Thanks!